# How to reference user object in a generic Symfony2 lib?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, bundle

When creating a bundle which is not for one application only, but thought for a more generic use, lets say a ChatBundle, I always hit the same problem about how to use an user object which of course is needed in many cases (like in a chat).

In a bundle which is only used in one application, I simply hard code a reference to my main bundle like this:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\ChatBundle\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Message
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\ProjectBundle\User")
     */
    private $user;
...
```

But in a generict bundle this isn't possible. Is the only way to let the developer implement all entities on his own? Are there any best practices? I could not find any documentation or blog posts about that topic, except the code of other bundles (but most of them are that complex and abstracted that it's hard to grasp the main issue there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution here is to use [Doctrine's TargetEntityListener](http://tim.nagel.com.au/symfony2/doctrine2/using-doctrines-resolvetargetentitylistener/)